# Usercontrol runtime width and height

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, user-controls

I am trying to create a simple User Control (not WPF) in VS2008 which effectively is a `SplitContainer` with a button in `Panel1`, which when pressed, toggles the `Panel2Collapsed` property and resizes the control to the size of `Panel1`.

Here are the bare bones of the control:

```
private int _openHeight;
private int _closedHeight;

public MyUserControl(bool open)
{
  InitializeComponent();

  _openHeight = this.Height;
  _closedHeight = splitContainer1.SplitterDistance;
  Open = open;  
}    

private bool _open;
private bool Open
{
  get { return _open; }
  set 
  { 
    _open = value;
    splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = !_open;
    this.Height = _open ? _openHeight : _closedHeight;
  }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Open = !Open;
}
```

The problem is that `this.Height` in Runtime is the value which the control is in the User Control Designer, rather than what is set at Design-time in the main form's designer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Following on from Lucas' solution, this way means that the _openHeight is only set once, resulting in the desired effect:

```
private int? _openHeight;
private int _closedHeight;

public MyUserControl(bool open)
{
  InitializeComponent();

  //the _closedHeight doesn't change so can be defined in the constructor
  _closedHeight = splitContainer1.SplitterDistance;

  //set value
  Open = open;  

  this.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(MyUserControl_SizeChanged);
  this.Load += new EventHandler(MyUserControl_Load);
}    

void MyUserControl_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //this event is called BEFORE the _Load event so gets the height set in the designer
  //  and not any changes at run time (e.g. when you collapse the control)

  if (_openHeight == null)
    _openHeight = this.Height;
}

private bool _open;
private bool Open
{
  get { return _open; }
  set 
  { 
    _open = value;

    if (_open)
    {
      //sets height only if it has been initialized
      if (_openHeight != null)
        this.Height = (int)_openHeight;
    }
    else
    {
      this.Height = (int)_closedHeight;
    }
  }
}

void MyUserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //now that control is loaded, set height
  Open = Open;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Open = !Open;
}
```

Comment: Has the solution I suggested worked for you?

Comment: Just tested your second solution and, with a bit of modification, it works. Is it proper practice to update your answer with my modified solution?

Comment: Just make na **Update** in your question heading and update it with the answer you have and some description :).

Comment: I saw You edited my answer, but if you want I can discard it and just let You update the question and describe your own version based on my answer :).

Comment: Okay, reject away and I shall do an update on the question. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reading the control's Height property in it's constructor, which means it's probably BEFORE it shows in the form. The thing is, the size seems to be adjusted when the control needs to be show in the form. Before this, it's a value set in the control's designer, which you are now getting.

The easiest way to solve the issue is to read the `Height` value when you're sure that the control was already drawn in the form i.e. you can get `open` parameter out of the control's constructor, add a new method that initializes `Open` and `_closedHeight` and call it in `Load` event of the form.

Something like this:

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent(); 
}

public AdjustControlSize(bool open)
{
    _openHeight = this.Height;
    _closedHeight = splitContainer1.SplitterDistance;
    Open = open; 
}

//the rest of the control's code is unchanged
...
```

Then call `AdjustControlSize` method from form's `Load` event.

**Solution with eventing mechanism**

You can also use control's own events to read the `Height` when appropriate. This way you don't have to change anything in the `Form`'s code.

So, in this case, the code can look like this (I haven't tested this though):

```
public MyUserControl(bool open)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _openHeight = this.Height;
    _closedHeight = splitContainer1.SplitterDistance;
    Open = open;
    this.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(MyUserControl_SizeChanged);
}

void CustomPictureBox_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _openHeight = this.Height;
    _closedHeight = splitContainer1.SplitterDistance;
}
```

This way the control can self adjust itself each time its size is changed.